# ng-hide/ng-show within an ng-hide/ng-show not working properly in **chrome** on first trigger, second time it reflects just fine

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, ng-show

I am having a scenario where an edit input with the suggestion list is there, when I do the entry on ng-change the list appears with the relevant suggestions, and shows exception if no data is available. But in chrome I am having an issues that without the search(ng-change) itself the list with the input appears showing "No data exception"

I am having something like this:

```
<div ng-show="show on a condition to edit">
  <input  ng-change="callForservicetoDisplayList()" ng-model="enteredValue"/>
  <ul ng-show="only when callForservicetoDisplayList function returns value">
    <li ng-repeat="outputFromthe callForservicetoDisplayList"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here the list appears from before itself in chrome on first edit, second time works fine!

Comment: Could you show all your code ?

Comment: worked around by initially setting the list as display none thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug ! So
This should be fixed in latest 1.4 (1.4.9). You are using an outdated version

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13380